# How to smoothly scrolling in adding element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I making infinite scroll box by clicking two arrow ! I do each scroll by adding/subtracting `15px` . I detected the scroll left `min` and `max` value for making infinite scroll by adding existed element , but its scroll range is not going to `15`.It is scrolling to the whole div width . How can I make it scrolling to `15` (px) after I added element (not its element width) ?

```js
$("#left").click(function(){
  var left = $("#round").scrollLeft() - 15;
  if(left == -15) {
     $("#round div:last-of-type").remove().prependTo("#round");
  }
  $("#round").scrollLeft(left);
});

$("#right").click(function(){
   var left = $("#round").scrollLeft() + 15;
   if(left == 315) {
     $("#round div:first-of-type").remove().appendTo("#round");
  }
   $("#round").scrollLeft(left);
});
```

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0px;  /* remove scrollbar space */
    background: transparent;  /* optional: just make scrollbar invisible */
}
/* optional: show position indicator in red */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: transparent;
}
#round {
 max-width:500px;
 max-height:100px;
 width:500px;
 height:100px;
 border:1px solid #bbb;
 overflow:auto; 
 display: -webkit-inline-box;
 position:relative;
}

#round div{
width:200px;
height:inherit;
}

#one {
 background:red;
}
#two {
background:pink;
}
#three {
background:green;
}
#four {
background:#393939;
}
span {
  position:fixed;
  border:1px solid #bbb;
  padding:10px;
  background:rgba(255,255,255,.5);
  color:#eee;
  top:30px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
#left {
 left:10px;
}
 #right {
 left:475px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="round">
    <div id='one'>1</div>
    <div id='two'>2</div>
    <div id='three'>3</div>
    <div id='four'>4</div>
    <span id='left'>&lt;</span>
    <span id='right'>&gt;</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may modify your code like this. When you reach the `left==-15` you consider **adding** the width of the new element you add in the left and then you scroll. You do the same in the right but you **remove** instead of adding :

```js
$("#left").click(function() {
  var left = $("#round").scrollLeft() - 15;
  if (left == -15) {
    $("#round div:last-of-type").remove().prependTo("#round");
    left = $("#round").scrollLeft() + $("#round div").width() - 15;
  }
  $("#round").scrollLeft(left);
});

$("#right").click(function() {
  var left = $("#round").scrollLeft() + 15;
  if (left == 315) {
    $("#round div:first-of-type").remove().appendTo("#round");
    left = $("#round").scrollLeft() - $("#round div").width() + 15;
  }
  $("#round").scrollLeft(left);
});
```

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0px;
  /* remove scrollbar space */
  background: transparent;
  /* optional: just make scrollbar invisible */
}


/* optional: show position indicator in red */

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: transparent;
}

#round {
  max-width: 500px;
  max-height: 100px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  overflow: auto;
  display: -webkit-inline-box;
  position: relative;
}

#round div {
  width: 200px;
  height: inherit;
}

#one {
  background: red;
}

#two {
  background: pink;
}

#three {
  background: green;
}

#four {
  background: #393939;
}

span {
  position: fixed;
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  padding: 10px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
  color: #eee;
  top: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#left {
  left: 10px;
}

#right {
  left: 475px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="round">
  <div id='one'>1</div>
  <div id='two'>2</div>
  <div id='three'>3</div>
  <div id='four'>4</div>
  <span id='left'>&lt;</span>
  <span id='right'>&gt;</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Can I have like this `left (+/-)= $("#round div").width();` in your answer !

Comment: @DavidJorHpan yes of course, it's even better so you have a generic code. I also updated my answer. I used fixed value as i saw it fixed in the css ;)